# git push/pull origin [branch] shortcut?

Tags: git, push, commit

I've been using git in the console for the last couple of months and I feel like there's a little too much typing.

Here's my flow (assuming I'm on `foo` branch):

```
[ ... working ... ]
git add .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git pull origin foo
git push origin foo
```

I know it's one of first world problems but is there a way of cutting the typing here? Can I just use `git pull` and `git push` for example? What's the difference between `git push`, `git push origin foo`?

Comment: And don't forget to configure and use bash command-line completion.

Comment: I set up aliases, `gph` is `git push`, `ga` is `git add`, etc

Answer (score 8):

For `git push`, you can configure to automatically push to remote branch with the same name as local using configuration.

`git config push.default current`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault

For `git pull`, you will need to make local branch tracking branch to remote branch.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279975/1433665

Comment: The referenced so question is `the` reference, for me.

Comment: I've been wondering how to do this for ages while also putting off the time to figure it out. I always just want to push the current local branch I am on when I run this command and I think "typing out the same branch I am on seems redundant and unnecessary". Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
git commit -am 'subject: research the commands, Luke!'
git push
```

is equivalent unless you've added new files yourself, so you need to tell Git to hunt them down and track them with `git add .`, or  `git push` sees new history on the remote branch you're tracking that you didn't know about already, so you need to pull first.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following shortcut to push your local branch to the remote repository and create a new branch with the same name on the server

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```

In this way, you avoid typing

```
 git push --set-upstream origin _your_possibly_very_long_branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a "shortcut" actually, but definetely reduce amount of typing:

Once:
`git push --set-upstream origin foo`

Then:
`git push` and `git pull`

Comment: I don't get this workflow, I've been doing this for a while but it's way too easy to forget to set upstream if you have a lot of branches.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Maybe you could use aliases in **~/.bashrc** like ```alias gplo="git pull origin"``` and ```alias gpho="git push origin"``` in order not to break existing workflow.

Answer (score 0):

To push your local branch: `git push origin head`
To pull to your local branch: `git pull origin $(git branch --show-current)`

I realise that the last one is a bit too long to type, so you can wrap it in an alias like this:
`alias gitpull='git pull origin $(git branch --show-current)'`

Then just execute `gitpull`