# Have git figure out that remote branch name matches local branch name automatically with multiple remotes

Tags: git

For reasons that are outside the scope of this question, we have multiple git repositories, which I will call `origin` and `alt`.  Origin is the default repository, so

```
git pull origin
```

or even

```
git pull
```

will pull the current branch from `origin`.  However,

```
git pull alt
```

will fail:

```
<messages about object counts>
You asked to pull from the remote 'alt', but did not specify 
a branch.  Because this is not the default configured remote 
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

Is there a way to tell git that the branch name at the remote will always match the local branch name, so that `git pull <remote>` works, whether the remote is the default or not?

**Note**: I don't want to change the default remote.  At various times, I need to pull from both remotes.

Comment: I’m getting a flashback that LeGEC gave this answer last week or so… `git pull <remote> $(git branch --show-current)`

Comment: [This looked relevant but wasn’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279937/how-do-i-configure-git-to-automatically-pull-from-current-branch-when-using-git)